# Having a preselected option in a JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

***Background:***

I am creating a GUI for a cruise company. The user of the system can perform tasks such as: add new ships, decks, cabins and cruises with the use of the GUI.

***The problem:***

In my system, I have added the ability to duplicate a cruise, so once a selected cruise has been chosen to duplicate, a separate frame opens which is pre-populated with data from the cruise from which it is being duplicated from. However, the separate frame which opens (lets call it "duplicate cruise frame"), this frame also has a JList which assigns a ship to the cruise.

***The question:***

I need the JList in the duplicate cruise frame to have the ship it is assigned to already highlighted in the JList.

For example, if I have a cruise with the following data:

```
SHIP NAME: Pegasus
START PORT: Oban
END PORT: Teran
ASSIGNED TO SHIP: Scottie
```

Upon clicking the "duplicate" button I want the JList in the duplicate cruise frame to already have: `ASSIGNED TO SHIP: Scottie` highlighted.

***Code snippets:***

This is the JList which is holds data about the Ships (an array of ships):

```
JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
shipList = new JList(fleet.getShips().toArray());
scrollPane2.setViewportView(shipList);
shipList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
shipList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
southPanel.add(scrollPane2);
wholeFramePanel2.add(southPanel);
addCruiseF.add(wholeFramePanel2);
addCruiseF.setVisible(true);
```

***What I have tried:***

```
shipList.setSelectedIndex(shipList.getSelectedIndex());
```

and...

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
     Object o = model.getElementAt(i);
     if(o.equals(cruise.getShip())){
       shipList.ensureIndexIsVisible(shipList.getSelectedIndex());
      shipList.setSelectedIndex(i);  
                }
            }
```

Though neither of the two approaches above seem to highlight the ship the cruise is assigned to. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will of course do nothing:

```
shipList.setSelectedIndex(shipList.getSelectedIndex());
```

Because you're trying to select the list with the selection from the **same** unselected JList. It's the right idea, but you need to use the selection index from the **original** JList. The specifics of how you would do this will depend upon how your program is structured, but I'll bet you will be able to figure this out.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. Nevertheless, your suggestion was implemented and it did in fact work, thank you very much.